# Push result of each query into array

Tags: plpgsql

I've created function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION citiesById(integer[]) RETURNS text[] AS
$$
DECLARE

element int;
result text[];

BEGIN
  FOREACH element IN ARRAY $1
   LOOP
     WITH t1 as (SELECT city FROM cities WHERE id = element)
     SELECT city FROM t1 INTO result;
   END LOOP;

RETURN result;

END

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm trying to execute queries in a loop and insert result of each query into array to get something like `['London', 'Paris', 'Moscow']`. But I'm getting an error:

[image: error]

Is there a correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION citiesById(integer[]) RETURNS text[] AS
$$
DECLARE

element int;
result text[];

BEGIN
  FOREACH element IN ARRAY $1
   LOOP
     result := array_append(result, (SELECT city FROM cities WHERE id = element)::text);
   END LOOP;

RETURN result;

END

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```